# Product with any space preserves pushout of spheres

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that if $D$ is a pushout of the diagram $B \gets A \to C$, then $D\times X$ is a pushout of the diagram $B\times X \gets A\times X \to C\times X$, if $X$ is a nice enough space, e.g. if $X$ is locally compact.

My specific question is whether for the pushout $S^d$ of the diagram $S_+^d \gets S^{d-1} \to S_-^d$, where $S_\pm^d$ are hemispheres of $S^d$ and the maps are inclusions, the product with *any* space $X$ would preserve the pushout in the above sense.
Spheres seem nice enough for that to be true.